# Disconnect a jquery connection after an inactivity period

Tags: javascript, jquery, tcp, keep-alive

I'm using [TCP keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) on the server side to keep the connection alive, and notify the server if the client dies. How can I configure [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to disconnect the connection after a certain period of idle time?

Edit - I would like to consider "idle time" as time where no TCP packets are exchanged. Since the Server has TCP keepalive, it will constantly send 0-data packets to the client.

@J-P's answer is not an exact match for what I want. If the connection is open, has keep-alive traffic but no data, I would like to keep it open indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this can be controlled by JavaScript. If there are no requests left, I think the browser is free to end the connection. And that's all you can do with an XmlHttpRequest: Open or close connections.

Comment: There is an open outgoing request on the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `timeout` option:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '...',
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function(){ /*...*/ }
});
```

Or, if you want the same timeout for all requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 3000
});
```